# On what thread are event handlers executed?

Tags: android

On what thread are event handlers (like onAnimationEnd, onTouchEvent, onKeyEvent, onClick) executed? Are they called sequentially or can two handlers may execute simultaneously?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> On what thread are event handlers (like onAnimationEnd, onTouchEvent, onKeyEvent, onClick) executed?

The main application thread.

> Are they called sequentially or can two handlers may execute simultaneously?

They are called sequentially.

Comment: Main application thread is the thread where UI changes happen?